# Rotate an image without black area

Tags: python, image-processing, scipy

When we use some image processing library to rotate an image, the rotated image will always contains some black area. For example, I use the following python code to rotate an image:

```
from scipy import misc
img = misc.imread('test.jpg')
img = misc.imrotate(img,15)
misc.imsave('rotated.jpg')
```

The image is as follows:

[image]

My question is: how can I rotate an image without producing black area. I believe there exists some interpolation method to compensate for the missing area, which makes the image more **natural**.
It will be appreciated if anyone can provide a python code to achieve my task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to 'clone' or 'heal' the missing areas based on some part of the background, that's a complex problem, usually done with user intervention (in tools like Photoshop or GIMP).

Alternatives would be to fill the background with a calculated average colour - or just leave the original image. Neither will look 'natural' though.

The only approach that will work for all images will be to **crop** the rotated image to the largest rectangle within the rotated area. That will achieve your objective of having no black areas and looking natural, but at the cost of reducing the image size.

Comment: Thank your for your approach,it seems that I can only achieve my purpose in this way.

Answer (score 0):

isnt there a simple paint fill function in your "*some image library*" ?, simple do that at all 4 corner pixels and then make it white or so.

Comment: I didn't find any useful function to realize my task.And make the missing area all black or white is not what I want, I just want the rotated image to be natural.I think Joe P's@Joe P solution is good for me.